# How to convert video in the background using PHP and ffmpeg

Tags: php, windows, video, ffmpeg

I allow users to upload videos and then they get converted using ffmpeg. The video takes a really long time to convert which usually results in an error. I have done my research with no luck as to where I should get started.

Basically what I want to do is allow the user to upload the video and then display a message that says video is being processed and you will be notified when available. In the meantime I want the video to be converted behind the scenes and allow the user to leave the page or even close the browser. I am using a Windows server.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: by coding a basic queuing system ( ie. database table ), and running php from a cron job that checks the queuing system, and with set_time_limit.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to doing this kind of stuff. Do you have any examples or websites that I could learn more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic run-down of how to make your own queue using a scheduling system such as Cron:

- Create a database table `queue` containing `(id, created_at, file_path, id_user, result, error)`. The `file_path` contains the location of the uploaded video to process, the result is `null` before processing and then `true/false` afterwards depending on success, and if it failed `error` contains any messages. The primary key of the user table can be saved here too, if appropriate.
- Every minute, run a Cron program to check the queue for any unprocessed items.
- If there are items waiting, loop through a few of them and run your video conversion code. You may wish to limit this so that no more than, say, five items are processed in one go, and any more queued items have to wait for a new cron run.
- At the start of your cron script you need to exit early if an old copy is already running. You can use the output of `ps aux | grep (scriptname)` to help here, if you are running in a *nix-like operating system.

Inside your web application, you need to somewhat modify the workflow - rather than expecting a video to be processed immediately, you need to:

- Request the video conversion by creating a new database row
- Redirect to a page that explains the video creation is in progress
- Periodically recheck the conversion status using web redirects, AJAX or Web Sockets.

This approach is very useful for shared hosting where you cannot install your own queue processors. However, if you are on a VPS or cloud system, you may wish to look into Gearman or [one of many other queueing systems](http://queues.io/). They are a bit more complex than the above, but have more features for managing queues of work.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Unfortunately I am not familiar with how to write Cron jobs and where to begin. I will need to start some research on that.

Comment: They are very easy, @iamthestreets. On shared hosting there is usually a control panel (e.g. cPanel, Webmin, etc) and if that's not available, using `crontab -e` will put your editor in crontab edit mode. From here, just copy an example from the web.

Comment: Thank you! Would I put `crontab -e` at the top of my php page?

Comment: @iamthestreets: no, this is a console command for Unix-like environments like Linux. What operating system are you developing on? Do you have console/terminal access?

Comment: i am on a windows OS. I have access to both console/terminal.

Comment: Ah right @iamthestreets, you don't have Cron - but you have something very similar, called "Windows Scheduler". It's a window in your control panel, and you need to create a new schedule calling `C:\path\to\php C:\path\to\your\script.php` (i.e. call the PHP binary with a script parameter). Can you give that a go? Use the dialogue box to set a frequency of, say, every 10 minutes to start with.

Comment: Once you have that working you can reduce the time, but you need to decide how to prevent a new scheduled call doing work if an old one is still in progress. I am not sure how to do that in Windows, but some research with a search engine will undoubtedly shed light on it.

Comment: Thanks. My host is actually on a Linux and I have access to Cron Jobs in cPanel so I will need to do a little research on how to use it. Thanks again!